# execute block of code on enter key press in datagridviewcell

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, winforms

We are trying to execute block of code on `enter key press` in `datagridviewcell` editing mode.But we are unable to find enter key press on `datagridviewcell` in `editing mode`.

Answer (score 1):

KeyDown will not work for a cell in editing mode, subclass DataGridView and override ProcessDialogKey like this.

```
protected override bool ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        // Your code here
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessDialogKey(keyData);
}
```

Comment: Sir what we want to do is, On pressing enter key in cell 1 execute block1 of code , and on pressing enter key in cell2 execute a block2 of code and so on. What block1 of code is it will show a modalbox which contains a listview.

Comment: I've shown you how to intercept the enter key, add your code to show the dialog box where I have indicated.

Comment: @user2541238 you have to refer `CurrentCell` property to determine which cell is in edit mode to execute your code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `dataGridView1_KeyDown` event as follows:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {                
                e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
                //block of code
            }
         }
```

Comment: Sir I tried but While i am editing the cell and pressing enter its not even firing the keydown event. But when i just enter the cell and instead of editing , press enter key its firing.

Answer (score 0):

Do following if you want to check which cell is being clicked. This is in VB.net. Extended what Gary has already suggested you.

Public Class Custom_DataGridView
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

Public Event DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed(ByVal keyData As Keys, ByVal CurrentCell As DataGridViewCell)

Protected Overrides Function ProcessDialogKey(ByVal keyData As Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
            RaiseEvent DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed(keyData, CType(Me, DataGridView).CurrentCell)
            'Return true 'Open this if you don't want to move to next cell, if you open this the cursor will not move to next cell in the column.
        End If
        Return MyBase.ProcessDialogKey(keyData)
End Function

End Class

Use this Custom_DataGridView instead of out of the box DataGridView Control and then you have to handle the DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed event as shown below in your form in which you have added this custom control.

Private Sub DataGridNameYouHaveUsed_DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed(ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys, ByVal CurrentCell As DataGridViewCell) Handles      DataGridNameYouHaveUsed.DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed
        MsgBox("In DataGridView_CustomEnterKeyPressed Event Handler for cell( : " + CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString + "," + CurrentCell.RowIndex.ToString + ")")
End Sub

You might have already solved your problem, just posting so that if somebody else (like me) is searching for a solution this might be useful to them.